# Keeping the accordion menu open to show selected menu item

Tags: accordion

I have the following code for an accordion menu (see below).

How would I keep the current page menu item showing as at the moment whenever I move onto the page the menu closes down to only the top level?

I was also wondering if it's possible to have the accordion menu open up on click AND a page open at the same time??)

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

```
function initMenu() {
$(".sub-menu").hide();
$(".current_page_item .sub-menu").show();
$('#menu li a').click(

function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        return false;
    }
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#menu ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('#menu')).slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        return false;
    }
});

$('.current-menu-item').parentsUntil('#menu').slideDown('normal');

}
$(function() {
initMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The initMenu() function, should look like this:

```
function initMenu() {
$(".sub-menu").hide();
$(".current_page_item .sub-menu").show();
$('#menu li a').click(

function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        return false;
    }
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#menu ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('#menu')).slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        return false;
    }
});

$('.current-menu-item').parentsUntil('#menu').slideDown('normal');

var FullCurrentURL = window.location.href;
var CurrentURLparts = FullCurrentURL.split("/");
var CurrentURLindex = CurrentURLparts.length - 1;
var CurrentURL = CurrentURLparts[CurrentURLindex];

$('#menu li a').each(function () {
    var fullLinkURL = $(this).attr('href');
      var LinkURLparts = fullLinkURL.split("/");
      var LinkURLindex = LinkURLparts.length - 1;
      var LinkURL = LinkURLparts[LinkURLindex];
      if (LinkURL === CurrentURL){
        $(this).parents("li").addClass("current-menu-item");
        $(this).closest("ul").css('display', 'block');   
    }
});

}
$(function() {
initMenu();
});
```